# ActionBar menu Changed it's behavior after I changed inheritance from Activity to AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

I took an older project of mine and imported it into Android Studio.
As part of it, I had to change inheritance from Activity to AppCompetActivity to support ActionBar with its new API.

Now I have an unexpected behavior as a result:
All menu items are flattened instead of being hidden behind the three dots menu icon like so:

**Inheriting from Activity:**

[image]

**Inheriting from AppCompatActivity:**

[image]

Any Idea?

**Edited:**

Here is my menu.xml:

[image]

Comment: Need to update your menu file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to update namespace `android:showAsAction` to `app:showAsAction` attribute. Use the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Menu Item 1"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Menu Item 2"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `app:showAsAction="never"` attribute for each menu item in `menu.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your menu item like below -

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/menu_download_all_audio"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/menu_download_all"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_ico_all_download"/>
```

Use `never` if you want to hide your menu in three dots icon.

Answer (score 0):

Add app:showAsAction="never" attribute for menu item in menu.xml file

```
<item
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="HOME"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
```